# WPF UI Freezes after resuming from screen lock (Win+L) in Windows

Tags: c#, wpf

I have two WPF forms that will interact with each other. When I login to my first form it hides and the second form shows after I successfully logged in.

However when I perform a screen lock (Win+L) and resume, the UI freezes but I can receive notifications in my app and I can close it but my timer in the UI and also other controls freezes.

I found out that the trigger of this issue is the hiding of my first form because I tried commenting the Hide() function in my first form and it went well. I tried to pass the first instance of my form to the second to solve it but it didn't went well.

Why is it that the 2nd form freezes when I call Hide() in the first form? Any solutions for this?

NOTE: My application is in singleton pattern.

LoginForm.cs (1st form)

```
MainWindow.mainWindow.setJSONVisible(getUsers);
MainWindow.mainWindow.SetLoginForm(this);
MainWindow.mainWindow.Show();
```

MainForm.cs (2nd form)

```
private LoginForm login;
// This is triggered when the window's visibility is changed.
private void Window_IsVisibleChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
       if (IsVisible)
       {
             if(_visible!=null)
                    Operations.DisplayUsers(_visible);
             Cursor = System.Windows.Input.Cursors.Wait;
             login.Hide();
       }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you provide some code?

Comment: @Sefe I already edited my post. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Solve a similar problem in which my splash screen had not been closed, just hidden, after changing the code to close it stopped the freeze.